# Loading layers in ArcGIS without displaying it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers

When loading any layer into ArcMap (with drag-and-drop), it is automatically displayed/rendered into the canvas. I didn't find any option for disabling this behavior. Any suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like you want a layer to be added with its visibility checkbox unticked.  At worst I think you will be able to do this with ArcPy's AddLayer.

Comment: @PolyGeo, thanks for the tip. Since I'm not familiar with ArcMap, I preferred the solution without ArcPy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"When you uncheck the Make newly added layers visible by default option on the General tab of the ArcMap Options dialog box, new layers that you add will appear in the table of contents but not be automatically turned on (drawn on the map)...."

This is in the tip on this page:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-layers-to-a-map.htm

...also, more details of options here:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/setting-arcmap-options.htm

Comment: If you add a screenshot, it will be more clear.

Comment: This may be better, includes a 'ripped' screenshot and more explicit directions for these types of options- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/setting-arcmap-options.htm

Comment: Thanks! It was an easy task to accomplish (but I was blind). =)